# Are there any distributions with a working on-the-fly hybrid graphics switcher?

Tags: graphics

vga_switcheroo is used in many distros (including Arch), but it would be nice to have real-time switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, real-time switching is simply not possible without restarting X, and due to the basic architecture of X it never will be.  That seems to be the basic limitation.  I've heard that Wayland offers some options in this direction.