# How to switch between GPU's

Tags: ubuntu, graphics

How can I switch between two GPU's on-the-fly using Ubuntu 11.04?

I have an Asus EEE1015PN intel N550 with two GPU's: GMA3150 and Nvidia ION2. For example Windows 7 will switch to the bigger CPU when I pull up a full HD movie.

Comment: Whith https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee I think I succeded to switch between the two GPU's (after i run the disable-nvidia script AND REBOOT i get a glxgears result: ~60 fps, and if i run the enable-nvidia and reboot i get about ~450 fps) - but aren't there any methods to do this without rebooting?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `vga_switcheroo` to switch between graphic drivers / GPU's, but it doesn't work on the fly. Watch [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16129/1925) for any on-the-fly solutions that come up.

One guy has written up a [very detailed tutorial](http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com/) on setting this up under Fedora 14/Ubunut 10.10. You might have to adapt for 11.0, but it seems to cover the bases pretty well.

Ubuntu has documentation for using this on their wiki under [HybridGraphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).

There is also a very useful overview of the process on the [Gentoo wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Vga_switcheroo).

An experimental alternative system using ACPI is available from the [Linux Hybrid Graphics blog](http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/) which has instructions for checking out and running the toggle app for several different graphics chipsets as well as ongoing documentary of different models.

Comment: ehh, how could i use this vga_switcheroo?

Comment: @Lance: I edited my answer with some links, but googling "ubuntu vga_switcheroo" worked very nicely. Always make some effort to find existing answers before asking questions.

Comment: there is no /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch !!!

Comment: You don't need three exclamation points for that. A note on how it gets enabled can be found in the section "Enabling vga_switcheroo" in the Ubuntu doc I linked.

Comment: either if i use modeset=1 -> there is no /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

Comment: @Lance: Did you use grep command shown with your kernel config file  to see if it was enabled in your release? Also there seems to be another method if you follow the links at the top of that page that works for people without that switch enabled.

Comment: it was enabled in your release? - YES

Comment: stackexchange is for clear Q&A. Please answer cleary. did you mean this link? http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-acpicall-module-to-switch-onoff.html

Comment: In my mind StackExchange is more about learning and helping others learn than about doing people's work for them. I don't have time today re-write an article that seems to be quite well written already. The subject matter is not something I'm qualified to write something better than is already available. The clear answer I tried to provide was the name _vga_switcheroo_ which you didn't know and some links which would point you in the right direction. If that's not enough you can wait for another answer or ask a more specific question.